# Celery beat_scheduler's task executed but didn't get registered in model django_celery_beat_periodictask

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I am trying basic implementation of celery worker and celery beat on the **windows PC**. The celery beat is sending the task successfully and the celery worker received the task from celery beat and executed the task. **The problem is there is no task registered in django_celery_beat_periodictask as expected.**

**Problem:** Why there are no task in django_celery_beat_periodictask?

**Addon questions:**

1. If there are no task in django_celery_beat_periodictask then how does the celery beat executing the task?
2. What are the another data sources where celery worker took the task?

**Project Tree**

```
celery_with_django
                 |- django_celery_project
                                        |- __init__.py
                                        |- settings.py
                                        |- celery.py
                                           other files
                 |- mainapp
                          |- tasks.py
                             other files
                 |- requirements.txt
```

**Commands to run the code**

```
django server: python manage.py runserver
celery worker: celery -A django_celery_project.celery worker --pool=solo -l info 
**# (without --pool=solo the terminal is hard to interrupt)
celery beat: celery -A django_celery_project beat -l info
```

**My code look like this**

**requirements.py**

```
amqp==5.1.1
asgiref==3.7.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
billiard==3.6.4.0
celery==5.2.7
click==8.1.3
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
colorama==0.4.6
cron-descriptor==1.4.0
Django==4.2.1
django-celery-beat==2.5.0
django-celery-results==2.5.1
django-timezone-field==5.1
kombu==5.2.4
prompt-toolkit==3.0.38
python-crontab==2.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
redis==4.5.5
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.6.3
tzdata==2023.3
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.6
```

**django_celery_project/**init**.py**

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

**django_celery_project/settings.py**

```
**# other settings

**# CELERY SETTINGS

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

**django_celery_project/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_celery_project.settings')
app = Celery('django_celery_project')
app.conf.enable_utc = False
app.conf.update(timezone='Asia/Kolkata')
app.config_from_object(settings, namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f"Request: {self.request!r}")

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    '_test_celery_beat_schedule_': {
        'task': 'mainapp.tasks.test_celery_beat_schedule',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=10, minute=14),
        'args': ("Hello user, ",)
    },
}
```

**mainapp/tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
import time

def internal_func():
    print("--> internal func")

@shared_task(bind=True, name='_test_celery_worker_')
def test_celery_worker(self):
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(2)
        print(i)
        internal_func()
    return "Celery worker worked"

@shared_task(bind=True)
def test_celery_beat_schedule(self, msg):
    print(msg + " the task will be executed every day!")
    return "Celery beat_schedular worked"
```

[celery beat terminal, beat sent the due task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjYVB.png)

[celery worker terminal, worker received the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/153oh.png)

[empty django_celery_beat_periodictask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65JXA.png)

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this out on some of my projects and never noticed this, But it is true and the tasks that are registered on celery beat are not being shown in celery terminal on the initialization.

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    '_test_celery_beat_schedule_': {
        'task': 'mainapp.tasks.test_celery_beat_schedule',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=10, minute=14),
        'args': ("Hello user, ",)
    },
}
```

you registered the taks on celery beat with this makes it to work like this.

Comment: The task does show up in the celery terminal on the initialization. My concern is it's not registered in model django_celery_beat_periodictask of my database which I want to keep track of.